# php set configuration directive via shell

Tags: php, shell, console

I have an issue regarding php and it's configuration directives a.k.a settings in php.ini file.

I am currently developing a script that set ups a webserver and I need to set a few configuration directives.

```
$ php -d date.timezone[=Europe/Paris]
```

throws following error

```
PHP: sytnax error, unexpected END_OF_LINE, expecting '=' in Unknown on line 8
```

Further the script does not stop until I cancel it.

One of my other tries was:

```
$ php -d /etc/php5/cli/php.ini -d date.timezone=Europe/Paris
```

which does not throw an error but does not stop until I cancel it.

I have taken the above script from [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/de/features.commandline.options.php) I have not found a proper description either.

I appreciate any kind of help - it can be a link to a good description or a description by yourself.

Greetings,
AMartinNo1